# Need help creating/using variables in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

I just have a simple code and I hope a simple solution. I just want to create a variable in oracle and use it later on. I'm getting errors about needing a into clause or asking me to enter binds. I've been messing with this for 2 days now. Can someone please explain.

```sql
DECLARE
    BEGIN_DATE VARCHAR2 (20) := '12/31/2017';
    END_DATE VARCHAR2 (20) := '01/01/2019';

BEGIN

SELECT 
    STATUS
    , EQUIPMENT_ID "Eq_ID" 
FROM CYNFLEET.V_EQUIPMENT_INFO
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND STATUS Not In ('T','N')
    AND SOLD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(:BEGIN_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:END_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < TO_DATE(:BEGIN_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') OR STATUS Not In ('T','N') 
    AND SOLD_DATE Is Null 
    AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < TO_DATE(:END_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
END;
```

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: The error is nothing to do with the variables you have decalred - your `select` doesn't have an `into` clause, which is what the error text says. You need additional variables to put the query results into. [Read about the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html).

Comment: In PL/SQL, when you run a SELECT statement, you need to store the results somewhere. That means you need to do `select ...[bulk collect] into .... from ....`, with the relevant variables set up to hold the returned data (e.g. array(s) for if you're expecting more than one row, scalar variables if you're expecting a single row). What is it you're trying to do and why? If it's just to output some data, you can do that in SQL without needing to worry about the data being returned.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have shown is fairly select-explanatory; [as shown in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html), you need to select *into* something - which is what the error says. You will need to declare additional variables to accept the query results; but only if your query returns a single row. If it returns multiple rows you will need to select into a collection, or use a cursor and iterate over those results.

You will get messages about bind variables because... you are using bind variables in your query. You should not prefix local PL/SQL variables with a colon. Bind variables are set by the client, not within the PL/SQL block.

```
DECLARE
    BEGIN_DATE VARCHAR2 (20) := '12/31/2017';
    END_DATE VARCHAR2 (20) := '01/01/2019';
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
      SELECT 
          STATUS
          , EQUIPMENT_ID "Eq_ID" 
      FROM CYNFLEET.V_EQUIPMENT_INFO
      WHERE 
          1=1
          AND STATUS Not In ('T','N')
          AND SOLD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(BEGIN_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(END_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
          AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < TO_DATE(BEGIN_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') OR STATUS Not In ('T','N') 
          AND SOLD_DATE Is Null 
          AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < TO_DATE(END_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    )
    LOOP
      -- do some thing with each row's rec.status and rec."Eq_ID"
      dbms_output.put_line('Got status ' || rec.status || ' for ' || rec."Eq_ID");
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or with date-type variables and literal values:

```
DECLARE
    BEGIN_DATE DATE := DATE '2017-12-31';
    END_DATE DATE := DATE '2019-01-01';
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
      SELECT 
          STATUS
          , EQUIPMENT_ID "Eq_ID" 
      FROM CYNFLEET.V_EQUIPMENT_INFO
      WHERE 
          1=1
          AND STATUS Not In ('T','N')
          AND SOLD_DATE BETWEEN BEGIN_DATE AND END_DATE
          AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < BEGIN_DATE OR STATUS Not In ('T','N') 
          AND SOLD_DATE Is Null 
          AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < END_DATE
    )
    LOOP
      -- do some thing with each row's rec.status and rec."Eq_ID"
      dbms_output.put_line('Got status ' || rec.status || ' for ' || rec."Eq_ID");
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You need to be careful as `between` is inclusive; given your values you might actually want:

```
          AND SOLD_DATE > BEGIN_DATE
          AND SOLD_DATE < END_DATE
```

though it's hard to tell. As dates include times it would be more common on set your begin date to the first date you want information from (not, as it appears, the day before) and then use `SOLD_DATE >= BEGIN_DATE`.

You also need to be careful about operator precedence and evaluation order, as you are mixing `and` and `or`. It's better to be explicit about which bits of logic are tied together; it looks like you might want:

```
          AND STATUS Not In ('T','N')
          AND (
            (
                  SOLD_DATE > BEGIN_DATE
              AND SOLD_DATE < END_DATE
              AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < BEGIN_DATE
            )
            OR
            (
                  SOLD_DATE Is Null 
              AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < END_DATE
            )
          )
```

---

If you did actually want to use bind variables and just display the output then you would set those in your client and use plain SQL; e.g. in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, SQLcl and possibly others:

```
-- client variables
var BEGIN_DATE VARCHAR2(10);
var END_DATE VARCHAR2(10);

-- set variables via a PL/SQL block
BEGIN
  BEGIN_DATE := '2017-12-31';
  END_DATE := '2019-01-01';
END;
/

-- plain SQL query
SELECT 
    STATUS
    , EQUIPMENT_ID "Eq_ID" 
FROM CYNFLEET.V_EQUIPMENT_INFO
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND STATUS Not In ('T','N')
    AND STATUS Not In ('T','N')
    AND (
      (
            SOLD_DATE > TO_DATE(:BEGIN_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        AND SOLD_DATE < TO_DATE(:END_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < TO_DATE(:BEGIN_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      )
      OR
      (
            SOLD_DATE Is Null 
        AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < TO_DATE(:END_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      )
    );
```

Now those variable references in the query *are* actually bind variables, so they do have the colon prefix.

Comment: can you give me an example of what should go in the loop.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do with the data after you've retrieved it. I've added a `dbms_output` call, just so there is something there; but if all you want to do is display the selected data then as Boneist said you should be using a plain SQL query, not PL/SQL.

Comment: @akaballer8 - I've added a plain-SQL version that does use bind variables; I think that might be what you were originally trying to do. But it still ins't clear...

Comment: You can make your code simpler and easier to read by initially defining start date and end date as DATE not as varchars. Them remove all the to_date calls. Basic rule: **Always define dates as DATE (or timestamp).** If you must do a conversion do it as soon as possible and then leave it as date for all processing.

Comment: @Belayer - that's what my second code block does? I left them as string in the bind version because `var` doesn't support strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need stock the result of your selection in a variable with INTO clause.

```
DECLARE
BEGIN_DATE VARCHAR2 (20) := '12/31/2017';
END_DATE VARCHAR2 (20) := '01/01/2019';
VAR1 varchar2(100);
VAR2 VARCHAR2(100);
 BEGIN

 SELECT 
   STATUS
   , EQUIPMENT_ID "Eq_ID" 
    INTO VAR1, VAR2
 FROM CYNFLEET.V_EQUIPMENT_INFO
 WHERE 
  1=1
  AND STATUS Not In ('T','N')
  AND SOLD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(:BEGIN_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:END_DATE, 
  'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < TO_DATE(:BEGIN_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') OR STATUS Not In ('T','N') 
   AND SOLD_DATE Is Null 
   AND IN_SERVICE_DATE < TO_DATE(:END_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND ROWNUM <= 1;
 END;
```

But this works when the selection returns one column, if you need more columns, your variable must be a table type.

Answer (score 0):

You declare and use variables like this:

```
declare
    someVar varchar2(20) := 'Hello, world!';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(someVar);
end;
```

You populate variables from a query using

```
select a, b, c into x, y, z
from   ...
```

where x, y and z are variables.